# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated retorna sempre false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp-net-core

Estou implementando atorização e autenticação com identity utilizando o conceito de claims, após eu fazer o login, não estou conseguindo guardar a autorização, o login retorna 200 ok, mas não fica autorizado levando então para um status 401 sem autorização.

Startup.cs

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            });
```

UserController.cs

```cs
      private async Task<string>GenerateJWToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
            };


            //var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            //claimsIdentity.AddClaims(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));


            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token");
            claimsIdentity.AddClaims(await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                //new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

CustomAuthorization.cs

```
public class CustomAuthorization
    {
        public static bool ValidarClaimsUsuario(HttpContext context, string claimName, string claimValue)
        {
            return context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
                   context.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == claimName && c.Value.Split(',').Contains(claimValue));
        }

    }

    public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string claimName, string claimValue) : base(typeof(RequisitoClaimFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { new Claim(claimName, claimValue) };
        }
    }

    public class RequisitoClaimFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly Claim _claim;

        public RequisitoClaimFilter(Claim claim)
        {
            _claim = claim;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(401);
                return;
            }

            if (!CustomAuthorization.ValidarClaimsUsuario(context.HttpContext, _claim.Type, _claim.Value))
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, eu estava marcando como true, sendo que não estou utilizando essas verificações.

```
 ValidateIssuer = true,
 ValidateAudience = true
```

Bastou marcar para false

```
 ValidateIssuer = false,
 ValidateAudience = false
```